# Площади треугольников ломаной кривой из массива в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, координаты

Подскажите, как получить площади треугольников, которые образуются в результате ломаной кривой, начиная с третьего значения, так как первые два идут на первые две точки первого треугольника.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pass':[-3.076, -2.932, -3.168, -2.725, -2.416, -2.736, -2.88 , -3.162,
   -2.607, -2.275, -2.496, -2.516, -2.854, -2.506, -3.088, -2.537]})
```

То есть получается что нужны площади треугольников с координатами:
((0, -3.076), (1,-2.932), (2,-3.168)) , 
((1,-2.932), (2,-3.168), (3,-2.725)) и так далее. Заранее спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По [формуле площади Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0):

```
P = abs(x[1]*y[2] - y[1]*x[2] + x[2]*y[3] - y[2]*x[3] + x[3]*y[1] - y[3]*x[1]) / 2,
```

где вершины `(x[1], y[1])`, `(x[2], y[2])`, `(x[3], y[3])`.

Comment: спасибо, а как функция бы выглядела для новой колонки?

Comment: пока в такой форме это вижу:
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['area'] = abs(df['index']*df['pass'].shift(-1) - df['pass']*df['index'].shift(-1) + df['index'].shift(-1)*df['pass'].shift(-2) - df['pass'].shift(-1)*df['index'].shift(-2)) / 2

Comment: Мариан, спасибо большое! Без Вас бы не решил задачу. Сейчас пока что сделал df['area'] = df['area'].shift(+2) и fillna(0), шифты в самой формуле поправлю потом.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться - откуда взялась данная формула для расчется площади треугольника?

Comment: @MaxU - применением знакомой [формулы Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) для многоугольников к треугольнику.-:)

Comment: @MaxU, вы прав (как почти всегда), большое вам спасибо, я забыл написать последние 2 члены. Уже поправил.

Comment: теперь совпадает)

Comment: спасибо, ребята! Вы мне помогли)